# Removing the last value in the 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am running this code, it outputs the value of the image as an Array but with four values the RGB and Alpha, how do I remove the last value so its just the RGB im dealing with.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import numpy as np

ImageLocation = Image.open("images/numbers/0.1.png")

#Creates an Array [3d] of the image for the colours
ImageArray = np.asarray(ImageLocation)

print(ImageArray)
```

This is my output is for each pixel and I only want the RGB to be output not the 4th Column.

```
[[[255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]
```

Comment: If this is a numpy array then `ImageArray[:,:-1]` would do it.

Comment: Are you sure this is 2D, not 3D? There should be 3 dimensions: X, Y, and R/G/B/Alpha, not necessarily in that order.

Comment: You seem to have cut off part of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice numpy arrays like so:

```
rgb = my_array[:,:,:3]
```

Also since you're using PIL:

```
im = Image.open("path/to/image")
rgb = im.convert('RGB')
```

Comment: Better now, though I suspect it's still not appropriate for the questioner's actual array (which is probably 3D, not 2D).

Comment: Correct, adjusted for PIL/cv2 images